# Realized I posted wrong question

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

So I had a question about a problem I encountered. I tried to reduce my example to reproduce it to the shortest possible code.

But by doing so, I made the mistake of removing the actual problem without noticing it and posted this (working) code on SO for explanation.

This is now the situation:

- I asked a question about a non-existent problem
- I received several good, upvoted, answers telling me that my code had no problem
- As is, the question is unlikely to help future readers
- I still have a question about the initial problem I encountered

I am wondering what my options are and which I should choose. I currently see three options:

1. Delete the question and ask it again, this time with the actual problem.
2. Edit the initial question with the actual problem. This has the disadvantage that the current answers are no longer valid answers and should be deleted / edited.
3. Disregard this question and ask another one, with a very similar title and very similar code.

The question was answered shortly after it was posted.

Comment: 1. is not an option if there is more than one answer, or any answer has been up-voted. 2. is typically frowned upon (any changes to a question that invalidates existing answers will give people the impression you are a "help vampire".)

Comment: And I'm ok with option 3.  After all, your question got answers.  And since your actual question is probably different from the other, go ahead and asked a (retroactive) follow-up question.  Link to the original if desired.

Comment: If the code "works", but your description says something else, then I don't see how the answers that you got can be useful. If they are useful (against all odds) then you should go with option [3], but if they miss the point or are generally not good, I would consider deleting or voting to close (off-topic > no repro or off-topic > mcve) if deletion is not possible. After it is closed 10k users might vote to delete.

Comment: 2. is not a solution. Changing the original question sufficiently that posted answers that were correct are no longer correct (or even relevant) is bad form indeed.

Comment: As ryanyuyu proposed, I'd ask another question in which I will link the initial one and justify the creation of the 2nd one.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So I went ahead and asked a new question. Both my question were downvoted but at least, I got an answer.

Comment: *I received several good, upvoted, answers telling me that my code had no problem* -- Whoops!

Comment: "*I received several good, upvoted, answers telling me that my code had no problem*" such answers are 99,9% of time not good answers, but good comments, since they just state that OP didn't provide enough informations to reproduce real problem. Maybe try to politely ask author of each upvoted answer to remove it, so you could delete this bad/unclear/unusable question and ask new proper one.

Comment: @ArtjomB. the initial question is now "on hold" (I voted to close it).

Comment: Don't worry, SO loves crap, by design. Otherwise you would obviously be able to delete your own question when you realized it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lundin you can while there are no upvoted answers, I presume that otherwise a moderator or even dev might have to get involved to make sure all parties would be acceptable to the solution, but that takes a lot of resources, more than storing the question would

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Possible work-around:

- Do ***not*** radically edit the original question so that it suddenly asks a different question. That would be the worst possible choice.
- Instead, make an edit to the original post where you preserve the question as it was, but state: "EDIT: I just realized the question doesn't make sense, because... [reasons]."
- Ask a new related question if needed, about the actual problem.
- In the original question, make a comment to your own question: "Possible duplicate of [link to new question]. Please close this one."
- High rep users will close the first question and it will eventually get deleted.

Comment: I guess that if the question adds no value to the site, it should be deleted, despite the rep that other users earned.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Indeed. But SO firmly believes in collecting crap and pretend it is something useful. As soon as you raise a question on meta "can we delete crap", no matter context, there's always people insisting that the crap is actually pure gold and must be preserved for the benefit on mankind...

Comment: In reality this seems sensible. Morally I dislike streams of "EDIT:"s being appended to a question; it's messy.

Answer (score 7):

An unfortunate situation, but it does happen. I applaud your desire to seek advice regarding the appropriate outcome.

Personally, I think it's worth keeping in mind the broader goal of Stack Overflow: to build and maintain a repository of **useful** questions, along with **useful** answers.

Unfortunately, as things stand now, your question does not seem useful. The answers, while they may be correct, are also not useful. By "useful", I mean that someone at a future time will be able to search the repository for the question, and find that having done so, one or more answers posted to your question will help them with *their* problem.

In my opinion, the best thing for the question is for it to be deleted. You can post a new question that contains the correct, useful information.

You may not be able to delete the question yourself, due to existing answers and upvotes. For that, you may require the help of a moderator. Another option, at least for the moment, would be to vote to close the question as "off-topic", using the "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior…" option as the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I voted to close the question and it is now closed as "off-topic".

Comment: This seems like the only effective way to go. Kudos to both of you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that there's already at least one upvoted answer (regardless of whether it should've been an error or not), you can no longer self-delete the post.

Not sure that there's a *best* option in such a situation (the best option would be to proof-read the code before posting), but this is what I'd do:

1. Accept an "answer" that says that the code has no problem. This will stop others from attempting to answer it.
2. Vote to close. Others will do the same and it will *eventually* be deleted.
3. Edit the question from:

   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do...

   to:

   > #### Note: This question is an error. There's no problem here.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do...

   The message could be customized. It's merely there to inform incoming/future visitors upfront that there's nothing interesting here and not to  bother reading any further.
4. Lastly, post a **new question** regarding your problem. Treat it as a new standalone question.

Comment: If the question is closed as "not reproducible", then adding the "there is no problem here" disclaimer is unproductive (and on an older question, this could disrupt the Roomba's ability to delete it in a timely fashion).

Comment: @cimmanon, The question would be one that is just posted, and the purpose of the message is to get the question closed asap. It notifies incoming visitors that they should vote to close too.