# What should I do if I asked the wrong question, and an answer made me realize that?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36991247/11912) on SO.

A comment on the original question (which I asked they post as an answer), after a few individuals had posted answers, made me realize that the question I had asked was actually not the problem that I was hoping to solve.

I wouldn't have such an issue with this normally, but the answers to the question I *asked* would be valuable to others in the future.

On the other hand, the answer I was looking for, and want to accept, negates the entire need to do what I was thinking of doing.

The [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) suggests that I should accept the latter:

> It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally [...]

On the other hand, [Realized I posted wrong question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303914/realized-i-posted-wrong-question) suggests I should accept the answer to the question and create a new question if needed.

Should I accept as answer the answer that actually solves the question I asked, and would be helpful to others in the future, or the question I *wanted* to ask?

Comment: Just post another question.

Comment: This is a lot more common than you might assume, a poor or incorrect problem definition is behind most any unsolvable problem.  Do not accept an answer you did not actually use.  The odds are high that somebody that googles your question some day might be similarly led astray.  If the commenter does not want to take the time to flesh-out his comment into an answer when just post it yourself and accept it.

Comment: He did post it as an answer, and it was the one I initially accepted before a comment discussion brought me here. Three of the answerers appear to work with the specific technology in question as part of their jobs (vendors/consultants, based upon knowledge of one of the companies they work for, and quick Googling of the others). Since the question I should have asked also wasn't asked and answered on SO, I opted for a combination of the above comment and the answer I've accepted below. Given how much Google juice SO has, I *believe* this will benefit others in my situation the best. Shrug :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I accept as answer the answer that actually solves the question I asked, and would be helpful to others in the future

Yes.  You would be doing a disservice to all of the people that come to the question looking for a solution to accept an answer that doesn't actually answer the question.  That is what the feature is there for, to be an indication to future readers what the question author felt the best answer to that question is, because that fact would make it more likely that it'd be an answer that would help them.

Of course, the alternative is to just not accept an answer at all, if you feel that you're not sufficiently well qualified to indicate what answer best solves the question that is actually being asked.

Comment: And, of course, vote up any and all good answers.  The psychic who figured out how to answer what the OP really wanted to ask deserves two upvotes; one person can't actually give him a second, but hey, psychic.

Comment: It wasn't so much that they were psychic, as I posed the problem, posted a solution that I was trying, and then asked a question about that solution since it wasn't working. Ah well. Thank you both. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on whether the original question is likely to ever be the right question.  If it's more-or-less inherently the wrong question, accept an answer that points this out rather than one that just answers the question.